# io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apiexception Gone

Tags: java, kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes Java client API https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java for fetching all node present. I am Getting Error-

```
io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException: Gone  
   at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:971)
   at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:883)
   at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.listNodeWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:33661)
   at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.listNode(CoreV1Api.java:33559)
```

here is my code

```
public V1NodeList continueQueryNodes(String _continue) {
        try {
            V1NodeList v1NodeList = coreV1Api.listNode(null, true, _continue,
                    null, null, LIMIT, null, CommonUtils.REQUEST_TIME_OUT, null);
            return v1NodeList;
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            logger.error("request k8s node api error", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

as I know, the cluster node size is 2000, the LIMIT was 200, I tried change this value to 500, but also get the same error

I also tried use token to access api-server with "/api/v1/nodes" directly,but it works well.

Please let me know if I am missing anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: version of Kubernetes Java client API is 10.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the root cause is parameter of api "_continue",it seems expired in 10min in default,in my code, the time cost over the TTL,so the api return a exception gone